# TSLint - You can bind only to public class members (templates-use-public)

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, tslint

I'm having some troubles with this rule (templates-use-public) and WebStorm. You can see it here:

[image]

What's the main purpose for this rule? What's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This rule is about accessing component's private members from the template. Private members are intended to be used in a class itself only; templates are executed outside of the component scope, so they shouldn't have access to privates. Please see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/D_O_1fqA9WQ/pRNQARRiBgAJ, https://github.com/devoto13/angular2-private-members-example.

As for highlighting, seems that incorrect errors positions are reported by codelizer. Please run tslint in terminal using `ng lint` - what is the result?

Comment: The problem was that I was using private members in the template... as you said :)

Comment: The command showed the exact line where the private members were used.